# Schema design (database architecture) for Boolean flag fields

Tags: python, sql, database-design, django-models, database-schema

### Background

The architecture is for a personal app for nearby restaurants. I am toying with two ways to store single value Boolean (true/false) flag values.

My background in robotics is forcing me to think about smaller DB footprint. I may be very wrong.

### The Project

This app would have restaurant names and certain single flag fields. These fixed properties will not change anytime soon:

### Option 1: Individual Flags in the same table or a specific 1:1 property table connected with  Restaurant ID.

```sql
Rest ID  | hasOutdoor | hasDelivery | hasWifi
Rest1    |  1         |  1          |  1     
Rest2    |  0         |  1          |  0
```

Programmatically, option 1 would be easy; to extract individual property for each restaurant.

### Option 2: One string field with all properties.

```sql
Rest ID | Property
Rest1   |  "111"             
Rest2   |  "010"
```

This would have a small DB footprint but programmatically very *heavy to process*.

Example in python:

```python
PropertySet = ['hasOutDoors', 'hasDelivery', 'hasWifi'] 
for eachChar in Rest1.Property:
    if int(eachChar):
        PropertySet.pop()
```

Output:

```
'hasOutDoors'
'hasDelivery'
```

---

### Major cons of Option 2:

1. Code and database object are mixed. This could kill the system if a new property is added in DB and same changes need to be made in code.
2. Difficult to code (and heavy on processing) "Get all Rest that have hasOutdoor property"!

**Is there a better way of storing 0/1 values or is Option 1 the best?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use boolean fields. They exist for a reason. Do you really think saving a few bytes (which arguably you might not be doing since databases do optimise storage) is really worth the trade off in terms of query speed?

Querying the database is MUCH faster than retrieving all the results and THEN using Python to limit those results.

A database is much smarter than that. Say you have 20 records. In 5 of them `hasDelivery` is true. If you run `SELECT * from restaurants WHERE hasDelivery`. Then (with proper indexing) it won't read all 20 records from disk. It will read 5 records and return them. Obviously I'm just kind of generalising and handwaving. But read up on the database implementation you decide to use.

Bottom line: Doing the processing in Python would mean that EACH query would have to read the entire dataset into memory. Which is an expensive operation. A DB query for records with a boolean set to true/false will only read those records off disk.

Comment: I can imagine laughing all the way to a mental asylum if I had to maintain a bit of code which said "this length 20 varchar represents all the boolean options for our model". Well, actually. I'd just rewrite it and migrate all the data to a sensible schema. But whatevs.

Comment: Got it. Since I am using SQLite for this small project. I would be using the integer (1,0) to store this since it does not support Boolean values for now.

Comment: Well, you're using Django as well. So the underlying dB implementation is abstracted. Just use `models.BooleanField`. At some point you may switch   db engine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a string is unlikely to require smaller storage. On a DBMS that directly supports Boolean type, it is in fact likely to be larger<sup>1</sup>.

Second, and more important, if you ever have to search for, read or write any of the flags individually, storing them together in the same field would violate the principle of [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity) and therefore the 1NF. That would prevent you from indexing individual flags and generally complicate the way you manipulate the data.

> Is there a better way of storing 0/1 values or is Option 1 the best?

If your DBMS supports Boolean datatype, go for it.

If not, you are still probably best off just using something like CHAR(1) for each individual flag. However, if your storage requirements are very stringent and you are confident you won't be violating the 1NF by doing so, you can pack several flags together within same integer field (using bitwise operations).

---

*<sup>1</sup> For example, MS SQL Server can pack several BIT fields into the same byte of storage. In contrast, 1 character within a string will take **at least** 1 byte (depending on character encoding, it may take more). Even on a DBMS that doesn't "natively" support Boolean datatype (such as Oracle), it will likely spend only one byte per "emulated" Boolean field, which is still not worse.*

Comment: Thanks Branko, after going through the 1NF relation I have come to a point where I have to define if certain properties are *forever* Boolean or may have a third. For example, hasDelivery  may actually be (hasDelivery, NoDelivery and TakeAway).